# why do pentaho jobs ran through kitchen take a lot of cpu resources?

Tags: etl, pentaho

could you please give some small explanation on what happens when kitchen.bat calls a job?

I can only guess that it instantiates it and that probably is the reason why my taskmgr spikes up whenever I call 5 jobs all at the same time. after a couple of seconds, the spikes would wind down.

or maybe not? would there be other reasons that the calling of jobs through kitchen uses a lot of resources?

would there be ways to save the cpu resources while taking advantage of parallelism (calling the jobs all at the same time)? are there optimizations that can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How exactly are you calling 5 jobs at the same time? in the shell script?  In which case the spike is because you're starting 5 JVM's at the same time - starting the JVM is relatively expensive.  And there should be no need to do this - you can do it all in one JVM and do the parallelisation in the job?

Kitchen itself doesn't specifically use a lot of resources. If your transformation has a large number of steps, then getting that going can take some time, but not ages.

Is this really a problem?  Why does it matter if your cpu spikes for a couple of seconds?  The point of parallelism is generally to max out the CPU/box/resource!

Comment: thanks for the answer, yes i'll just call the jobs in one job and that should only start 1 jvm. appreciate the help! on your last question, i'm in an organization that does get on alert when the resources being used by the server gets to 80% to 90% usage.

Comment: Ahh, I see why that's important then!